# Opening .NC file in R online rather than downloading it

Tags: r, netcdf, nc

I am trying to access the .nc file in R which can be found(downloaded) here:
https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/nclimgrid-daily/access/grids/1951/ncdd-195101-grd-scaled.nc

I tried using this function nc_open form ncdf4 library in R:

```
library(ncdf4)
tempnc <- nc_open("https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/nclimgrid-daily/access/grids/1951/ncdd-195101-grd-scaled.nc")
```

And this returns me this error:

> Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: file not found
> Error in nc_open("https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/nclimgrid-daily/access/grids/1951/ncdd-195101-grd-scaled.nc") :
> Error in nc_open trying to open file https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/nclimgrid-daily/access/grids/1951/ncdd-195101-grd-scaled.nc (return_on_error= FALSE )

However, I was able to read it after downloading it onto my local computer.

Is there a way to try streaming this .nc file online rather than downloading it into our local system?

Comment: use terra, anything that has GDAL works better than the actual netcdf api   in my experience https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/94ee1638df373c20f176b75c786581a8

Comment: Thanks! Will try that out!

Answer (score 0):

Try OPENDAP url instead if there is any available for your data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. While answering please provide context and applicability of the answer. The type of answer you have written is more suitable as a comment. When  you have sufficient reputation, you can comment.